# Not able to open new tab using selenium java in chrome latest version 65.0.3325.162

Tags: selenium

Below is my code for create new tab,open new window and switch to default window.
**CreateNewTab:**

```
 jse.executeScript("window.open();");
```

**Switch to OpenNewWindow:**

```
deafultWindowName=driver.getWindowHandle();
for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);}
```

**switchToDefaultContent**

```
driver.switchTo().window(deafultWindowName);
```

I don't see any error message/issue with code but when I execute it all action gets performed in the main window only and it doesn't open new tab or new window. Please suggest!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you might be using an older syntax?

I usually use this:
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.open('about:blank','_blank');");
//#Note: if you wanna hit a specific URL, Replace about:blank with you desired URL

You could also try any of the driver methods like:
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "t");